# Linq where custom class list compares against two DateTime values in hours of the year

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list of a custom class and I am trying to create a new list from that list where I need to return a date range in hours of the current year. I've been trying the following, but it returns a list of zero:

```
List<Core.tokenHistory> firstQuery = thl.Where(x =>
x.Date.Value.DayOfYear * 24 + x.Date.Value.Hour > day.Value.DayOfYear * 24 &&
x.Date.Value.DayOfYear * 24 + x.Date.Value.Hour < (day.Value.DayOfYear + 1) * 24)
.ToList();
```

It's very frustrating to me because I thought this code was working not a day ago, or perhaps that's just because I was programming while sleep deprived.

Edit: I've changed the original statement to my actual statement which uses DateTime? instead of DateTime and here is the custom class I am using:

```
        public class tokenHistory
    {

        DateTime? _date;
        string _action;
        string _recipient;
        int _tokens;
        int _balance;


        public tokenHistory(DateTime? date, string action, string recipient, int tokens, int balance)
        {
            this._date = date;
            this._action = action;
            this._recipient = recipient;
            this._tokens = tokens;
            this._balance = balance;

        }

        public DateTime? Date { get { return _date; } set { _date = value; } }
        public string Action { get { return _action; } set { _action = value; } }
        public string Recipient { get { return _recipient; } set { _recipient = value; } }
        public int Tokens { get { return _tokens; } set { _tokens = value; } }
        public int Balance { get { return _balance; } set { _balance = value; } }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `CustomClass` ?

Comment: I know the code is not working because firstQuery.Count = 0.

Comment: How do you calculate `today` and `tomorrow`?

Comment: Whoops, forgot that I was testing the variables outside of the query. Edited the post.

Comment: The only reason your code is not working is because no element in `thl` matches the conditions you have dictated in your `where` clause. Also you can redesign `tokenHistory` and use auto properties instead. Also consider using PascalCaseNamingConvention for C# class names.

Comment: Why don't you simply check whether `x.Date` is between `day` and `day + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

If the list you make your first query spans multiple years, there is no way this is going to work. I'm now creating my own class that contains two ints, one for the hours and one for the year. I can't believe it's taken me a full day to realize this...